# Fan motor capacitor replacement

Tags: air-conditioning, fans, electric-motor, capacitor

Could I get some help replacing this blown (and very smelly) capacitor from an air conditioner? It's for the fan motor.

[image]
[image]

The part is available here https://rmscomponents.com.au/shop/appliance-spare-parts/panasonic-spares/ds441355npqa/

Because of part shortage, I've got myself one of this:

[image]

https://www.tradezone.com.au/product/suntan-3-5-mf-450-volt-capacitor-23134.html

Are these actually compatible? I believe the one I got is a 2-wire run cap, because 2 of the 3 legs on the old cap are connected. Does anyone know why an AC fan motor would need 3 wires?

Does polarity matter here?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: 3.5 uF on both will work, did you actually measure if it is bad.

Comment: It is AC capacitor so polarity does not matter

Comment: @Ruskes I haven't taken it out yet, but it looks very bad. Some goo is leaking out from it. Do I only need to make sure the two wires on the bridged pins stay on the same U-shaped terminal on the new?

Comment: OK, it is dead, do not touch the goo with bare hands, it might contain corrosive chemicals, just plug it in, and see if it has enough juice to help start the motor. Before you do anything, take a picture of how was it wired

Comment: @Ruskes Fixed! All good now. Thanks.

Comment: Good job, we can fix anything